# scroll the page to show div position of page after post back

Tags: jquery

i am using the following jquery to scroll the page to specified div position while clicking on linkbutton. i am using the linkbuttons on top of the page and want from the page to navigate on specified div that is at the bottom of the page.

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%=linkbtn1.ClientID%>, #<%=linkbtn2.ClientID%>,  #<%=linkbtn3.ClientID%>, #<%=linkbtn4.ClientID%>').click(function () { 
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#grdDv").offset().top
        }, 800); 
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

i am using linkbutton events for all four linkbuttons as below, for performing some suitable work.

```
protected void linkbtn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Session["interval"] = 1;
        BindGrid(ID);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the linkbutton calls jquery it scroll the page to the required position, but after that, when codebehind event is get called the page goes to server and when it returns back it shows the top position of the page.

i want to use linkbutton's click event in each case, please help how to show the div that is available on bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restrict the page to show the specified position on page after call back, i used the following script rather than the above script.

```
 <script>
     var pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
     pageRequestManager.add_endRequest(function () {
         $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#grdDv").offset().top
         }, 800);
         return false;
     });
   </script>
```